# Как правильно произносится слово «туннель/тоннель»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Слышу часто «т**а**нель», «в т**а**неле». Как правильно?

Благодарю.

Comment: А как правильно Москва или Масква? Кто как хочет, так и произносит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Одни произносят через У, другие – через А. Оба варианта правильные.

> [**ТУННЕЛЬ; ТОННЕЛЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&all=x) *[нэ],* -я; **м.** [англ. tunnel] Сквозной коридор, проход под землёй или в горах. *Т. метро. Поезд нырнул в т. Подземный, подводный т. Двигаться по тоннелю (туннелю). Показаться из тоннеля (туннеля). Проложить т. в горах. Горные тоннели (туннели) Кавказа.* **<Туннельный; тоннельный,** -ая, -ое.

> [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=242362)
>
> *Тоннель* и *туннель* – равноправные орфографические варианты (т. е. это не разные слова, а разные варианты написания одного слова). В любом контексте возможно употребление любого из этих вариантов.

**Нацкорпус русского языка**:
*тоннель* – [**954** документа](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CocBEmUKYxJhChcKA2xleBIQCg7QotC%2B0L3QvdC10LvRjAoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKACoXCggIABAKGDIgCiAAKL6gzYqJhvoKQAUyAggBOgEBMAE%3D),
*туннель* – [**885** документов](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CocBEmUKYxJhChcKA2xleBIQCg7QotGD0L3QvdC10LvRjAoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKACoXCggIABAKGDIgCiAAKOytnt6a4uwGQAUyAggBOgEBMAE%3D).

Comment: Я против запятой в "и то и другое", потому что это чистое устойчивое выражение (не будь его, никто бы так не говорил), в отличие от "и первое и второе".

Comment: @oleedd Убрал, чтобы не было разногласий.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!